# Remotely connect to device with ip from different subnet

Tags: networking, routing, remote-access, fortigate

I have to figure out some way to remotely connect to D-LINK switch currently working on default address 10.90.90.90 (service guys have replaced broken one, but they have forgotten to do initial config). The problem is it's connected directly to lan port on my FortiGate 60D where I have 10.0.0.0/24 subnet.

This particular swith could be managed only by web GUI on 80/443 ports. I have only access to network equipment, there is no host inside network I could use to get into the switch GUI.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after some attempts I figured out how to connect. First thing was to add second IP address to internal interface in same subnet as D-LINK default IP, for example: 10.90.90.1/24. Second was to use SSL VPN to establish tunnel connection to router, but instead of using the default IP range for tunnel I've changed it to point to interface second subnet, in my case 10.90.90.200 - 10.90.90.210. Then, after establishing VPN connection I was able to manage this switch.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily set your PC address to 10.90.90.something and connect to the D-Link with a cross-over cable, reconfigure it to what you want, and then change your PC back and put the regular patch cords back where they belong.

Comment: I can't do anything localy right now. Only option is to setup FortiGate using DNAT or SSL VPN. I tried but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have remote access to a machine that is on the local LAN of the DLINK the you could:

1)  setup a subinterface on the remote machine to some address in the subnet 10.90.90.X
2)  after that you should be able to ping the DLINK from that machine
3)  then you can use Teamviewer or even setup a Proxy Server using Apache on that remote machine so you can talk to the DLINK.